# Comment spammer IP list?

Tags: spam

Is there a public list anywhere on the web of IP addresses that have been identified as comment spammers?

Comment: Spammers get new IP addresses when their old one is blacklisted, so I don't think an IP blacklist will be effective.

Answer (score 5):

For comment spam, have you tried [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) (written by the wordpress crew)? They have an API which you could use (if you're not using wordpress) and is $18 a year for a personal blog or $5 a month if you make money from it, so it's a bit of a deal.

**Edited for danlefree's comment**

I guess the free and up to 10,000 pageviews a month could be considered donationware as you can select how much you want to pay. If you select any of the checkboxes it puts a mandatory price on it.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation, however, I would add that Akismet is free for personal use until you hit 10k views per month - bears mentioning for hobbyist bloggers and UpTheCreek hasn't stated whether the blog is business-related. URL: http://akismet.com/about/

Comment: True. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Askimet is ideal for this

Comment: I looked at this before, and it seems interesting. But at this stage I don't want to integrate with a third party service.  However it's looking unlikely now that I'll find a simple list.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other recommendations, I would also check [Project Honeypot](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/), it allows you to check by the IP address of the request if they have exhibited malicious activity in the past (the lookup is performed [using a DNS query](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/httpbl_api.php)).

You can also contribute to the project by creating a honey pot (it is a page on your site that you link to through other pages which is not visible to your users) which will track harvesters.

Comment: Yeah I took a look at that, but was suprised that you couldn't just donwload a list of IPs.  Why not I wonder?

Comment: @UpTheCreek: It doesn't make sense to download an entire list; the list would be extremely long.  It's more cost-effective to serve up details about an individual ip than to return an entire list every time.  It's analagous to asking YouTube "give me all the videos you have".  On top of cost-effectiveness, the list will constantly change, so the client constantly downloading the entire list doesn't make sense given the fluidity of the data.

Answer (score 3):

another option is  http://defensio.com/  Only discovered this the other day so I am not sure how it measures up in catch rate etc against akismet..

Comment: Looks good. Never heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

You (really) don't want to download a list, you want a realtime service.

Check out [Akismet](http://akismet.com) and [StopForumSpam](http://www.stopforumspam.com/).

Blogspambl.com used to be active but I think it may be defunct now.