# IP Addresses of Known Spammers

Tags: spam, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment spammer IP list?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8966/comment-spammer-ip-list)

Is there a list out there that has IP addresses of known spammers? I wish to know so I can block them in my forum.

Comment: It's not a duplicate 'cause that question didn't even get an answer. I'm looking for a list, not alternatives